# jquery ajax requests with when is not executing properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to start 8 ajax get requests N number of times, my code is like:

```
var me = this;
urls.forEach(function(requests){
  $.when(requests.map(function(request){
    return $.ajax(request)
  })).done(function(data){
    me.result.push(data);
    //data is an array of 8 where every object is coming from those requests
  })
})
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the `done` functions callback every object is an empty ajax object, but if I wait for a little after the success function was called N times and I check `this.result` the data is correct there. Why is 'done' success called too early?

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of your code? What is the content of `urls` and what is `this`

Comment: I think the `.done()` is been apply to the `when()` function and not the `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an untested idea... Shouldn't it work a bit simpler...

```
var result = [];
var urls = ["http://url1.com","http://url2.com","http://url3.com"];

urls.forEach(function(str_url){
  $.ajax({
    url: str_url
  }).done(function(data){
    result.push(data);
    //data is an array of 8 where every object is coming from those requests
  });
});
```